# How to fix issue with some users not loading seeing Font Awesome icons, and not even empty rectangles?

Tags: font-awesome

I have a few websites that use Font Awesome (various versions) and in general have no problems. A user is reporting that they aren't seeing the icons. In other cases when there are font loading issues, I have seen empty rectangles instead of icons, but in this case it's just empty space.

I have checked one my sites that gets the icons via a CDN and one where I host them myself. They both work for all users except this one (as far as I know), so I don't think it's a hosting issue. The empty space without icons or the empty rectangle seems like an important clue - any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what browser (and version) they are using to access the site? What version of FA are you using and how do you use the icons? (CSS only or CSS/JS). Perhaps JS is disabled in the user's browser?

Comment: Turns out it was the Group Policy within an organization. I figured it had to be something on the user side, but just couldn't figure out from the outside.

Comment: I'm going to close this, as soon as I figure out how to :)

Comment: One way to close it would be to answer the q and then accept the answer. May fell like self-promotion, but thats completely legit.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the Group Policy within an organization. I figured it had to be something on the user side, but just couldn't figure out from the outside